# Java8 Collectors.groupingBy

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to groupingBy a Collection based on the LocalDateTime, but I only want to get the Hour, not the minutes, seconds...

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(cp -> getUpdateLocalDate())


public LocalDate getUpdateLocalDate() {
    return getUpdateDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
}
```

but I need also the Date, something like: `2018-10-12T09:00:00`, not only the hour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

note that `LocalDate` doesn't have a time-zone. instead, return a LocalDateTime from the method `getUpdateLocalDate` (might be worth renaming also) then truncate the LocalDateTime instance.

```
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(cp -> cp.getUpdateLocalDateTime().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS));
```

Answer (score 4):

[As said by Aomine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52776827/2711488), a `LocalDate` does not contain any time information, therefore, you have to change the method to return a `LocalDateTime` instead.

```
public LocalDateTime getUpdateLocalDateTime() {
    return getUpdateDate().toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
}
```

Then, you may perform your operation as

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(cp ->
    cp.getUpdateLocalDateTime().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS))
```